# JQuery selecting wrong __RequestVerificationToken

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am getting an issue on my page where I have 2 `__RequestVerificationToken`s being rendered (1 for the logoff form, 1 for a submit form which is rendered in a partial view).

Now everything works perfectly, but as soon as I add a `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` to my controller method, the server complains that no token is passed to the controller.

I am getting the token with

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    // ...some code
    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', this).val();
    // ...more code
});
```

But it always seems to get the token for the wrong form. Why is that? Shouldn't it be targeting the submitted form when using `this` when getting the value?

---

### Update

Here is my full ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    type: this.method,
    data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token, lead: formdata },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('form .btn').prop('disabled', true);
    },
    success: function (result) {
        $('form .btn').prop('disabled', false);
        $('form .form-control').val('');
        $('#result').html('Thank you. We will contact you shortly.');
        $('.validation-summary-errors ul li').css('display', 'none');
    },
    error: function (result) {
        $('form .btn').prop('disabled', false);
        alert(result.responseText);
        //alert('An error occurred on the server. Please try again. \n\n If this keep happening, please email us at office@auroraglobal.ru');
    }
});
```

I can see from setting up some `alert` boxes, that the token being select is definitely the wrong one (after viewing the source, I can see it is the value for the logoff form rather than the submit form).

I also tried setting `data` to simply

```
data : {token, formdata}
```

### HTML

logoff form

```
<form action="/ru/Account/LogOff" class="navbar-right" id="logoutForm" method="post">
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" 
        value="FIna8PhWML3zzw2m4ZRKdB-nDx_EZ7_1iWjdb6UUHZBsPG4RxrV4YXX5j56Qmd7Gs-UrCnoRZd-IM9MCx-fhvf9fKf4BZf0pUheuaJlI1_sVgT7L-nSCv8dOecmg5XeuQaZqXFYyUagZujIa_J1vzA2" />                    
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/ru/Manage" title="Manage">Здравствуйте skotze !</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/ru/Lead" id="leadsLink">возможности</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/ru/Organisation" id="leadsLink">организации</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/ru/Admin">админ</a></li>

            <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">выйти</a></li>
        </ul>
</form>
```

submit form (this is the token I am trying to get with the bove jquery)

```
<form action="/ru/Lead/Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="XWPLVZr1NRi41XvWg5OtrHzDcVzwcACktMbK6ygtbHwjRhnWIGWmeeKGlqhOQA5gag4dFCkOujeDjfjsW6U3E-WEnnJ85QbU7RrR02ltRnJWu6V-QnLUX5fAXCpBMmyk47NpSnUvDIkphUNDI-Ocgw2" />    <div class="form-horizontal container-fluid">
        <h4>Новый запрос</h4>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Необходимо заполнить местонахождение" id="Location" name="Location" placeholder="местонахождение" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Необходимо заполнить организация" id="OrganisationName" name="OrganisationName" placeholder="организация" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Необходимо заполнить Контактное лицо" id="ContactName" name="ContactName" placeholder="Контактное лицо" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Введите действительный номер телефона." data-val-regex-pattern="^(?!0+$)(\+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?(?!0+$)\d{10,15}$" data-val-required="Необходимо заполнить Телефон" id="Telephone" name="Telephone" placeholder="Телефон" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-email="Пожалуйста, введите действительный адрес электронной почты" data-val-required="Необходимо заполнить Email" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="" />
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <textarea class="form-control" cols="20" data-val="true" data-val-required="Необходимо заполнить Детали" id="Details" name="Details" placeholder="Детали" rows="2">
</textarea>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                    Файл <input id="fileInput" type="file" style="display: none;" name="Files" multiple="multiple"
                                                                      data-textbox="#fileUploadCount" data-singlemsg="1 выбранный файл"
                                                                      data-multimsg="Выбрано {0} файла">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
                <input id="fileUploadCount" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"
                       placeholder="вы можете выбрать несколько файлов" onclick="$('#fileInput').trigger('click');" />
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                <input type="submit" value=Отправить class="btn btn-default pull-right" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="validation-summary-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul><li style="display:none"></li>
</ul></div>
            <divi id="result" class="text-success"></divi>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's getting the wrong token, or is it that the value is not being sent correctly in the request? Without seeing more of your HTML and JS no one can give you a definitive answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your comment rory, I updated the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I also added my html

Comment: Might need to provide a working example of the problem, can't reproduce not getting the correct token: https://jsfiddle.net/9mnjypth/

Comment: @PatrickEvans After playing around with it  abit I managed to pass the correct value by surrounding `this` with `$()`, so it is now sending the correct value, however I still get the error complaining about the token not being sent through...this is so annoying I guess I should open a new question

Comment: What is `formdata` in `lead: formdata`? Based on your ajax options, it suggest you using `FormData` whch means you must use `.append()` to append the token to `formdata` or better, just use `var formdata = new FormData($(this).closest('form').get(0));` to serialize the for including the token